# Django form isn't rendering at all

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to make a non model form that just gets input text for a chat like interface.

views.py

```
def get_input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = inputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = inputForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


def shelley_test(request):
    form = inputForm()
    return render(request, 'shelley_test.html')
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

class inputForm(forms.Form):
    input = forms.CharField(label='input field')
```

shelley_test.html

```
<form action="/get_input/" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

please please help. I'm new at django and stumped :(

Answer (score 2):

You're not sending the form to the context in your `shelley_test` method - see the difference in the `render` line compared with `get_input`.

Note though you don't need `shelley_test` at all: just go straight to `/get_input/` to see the empty form.